# How to find a set of lat/long pairs surrounding a 5 miles radius of a certain location

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

How to find a set of lat/long pairs surrounding a 5 miles radius of a certain location expressed in lat/long or as a address.

Comment: what do you mean by set of lat/long pairs do you mean every lat long surrounding the certain location or some of the lat/long pairs

Comment: some of them would be preferable, but within a radius which I specify (say important landmarks or cities surrounding that lat/long)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031268/algorithm-to-find-all-latitude-longitude-locations-within-a-certain-distance-fro this might be helpful

Comment: Do you want some coordinates that build a circle or a rectnagle arround a center point given in lat/lon and radius in meter?

Comment: co-ordinates that build a circle, but definitely within the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you decide how many (lat,lon) pairs you want to have:
You could want to have 4 cordinates forming a square arround the center point.
Or you decide to have a regualr N-Gon around the center point.

Then you use a projection from lat/lon to meters, e.g EquiDistantProjetion.

This allows you to transform the lat/lon center to cartesian meters, 
where you then can calculate like you have learned it in school.

Now you having the center point in cartesian meters:
Then you use the Polar coordinate form of a coordinate (r, phi) to calculate the corner points of the square or N-gon.
(centerX + r* sin(phi), centerY + r* cos(phi)).

Finally you have to use the inverse tranformation to transform your coordinate pairs back to lat/lon.

The EquiDistantProjection works for distances up to some 100 miles. 
It does not work well above 80 deg latitude. (Polar region)