# between operator not working properly in varchar data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**setp-1** I have a table `tblRouteDetails` which given below

[image]

**step-2** and 
I am trying to find between places from placeName column but when i enter my query which are given below

**setp-3** select * from tblRouteDetails where placeName between 'Kaushambi'  and  'Maholi', it give [image]

**setp-4** so it skips middle row's records. but when I enter select * from tblRouteDetails where id between 1  and  6
[image]

it works fine. but i need find places by using placeName

Comment: Post text, not images of text please.

Comment: So lets see... K, L M  Do you have any other K's no... placeNames starting with L.. No... any M's yep just 1.  Results are as expected.  Now if you're wanting to do between based on physical lat/long of the place names and not the "NAME" of the place ; that's a different query.

Comment: It might be helpful to better describe what does  mean  'find places between'. If you'll apply BETWEEN on VARCHAR column it makes alphabetical sort, but that is obviously not what you are looking for.

Comment: Each **individual row** is evaluated against the `placeName` condition, and it seems clear to me that **only rows 1 and 6** are a match.

Comment: between isn't meant geographically, sql has no understanding of the earth's cities and countries. between is primarily used for numbers or dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below would be one way; but it seems like a strange requirement.  If someone adds a lat/long that falls between Kaushambi and Maholi it's ID may be higher yet physicaly it's between the two.  I think what you're wanting to do is consider lat/long and look for anything between +/- x kilometers from that line; between the two.  Something like this question: [Algorithm to find all Latitude Longitude locations within a certain distance from a given Lat Lng location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031268/algorithm-to-find-all-latitude-longitude-locations-within-a-certain-distance-fro)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblRouteDetails
WHERE ID Between (SELECT ID 
                  FROM tblRouteDetails 
                  WHERE placeName = 'Kaushambi') 
             AND (SELECT ID 
                  FROM tblRouteDetails 
                  WHERE placeName = 'Maholi')
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: it works fine but when I entered duplicate records, it gives an error 

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: ok.  so for example: Kaushambi has 2 different ID's (1, 23) which should the system pick?  you could wrap ID in a min() or Max() but without knowing which ID should be picked I'm not sure what you want to do when duplicates exist.  and note: between requires the first number to be less than the second.  If this isn't the case you may need to subsitute >= and <=

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select rd.*
from tblRouteDetails rd
where rd.id >= (select rd2.id
                from tblRouteDetails rd2
                where placeName = 'Kaushambi'
               ) and
      rd.id <= (select rd2.id
                from tblRouteDetails rd2
                where placeName = 'Maholi'
               );
```

In other words, you want the *rows* between the two values.  That is not what `between` does.  Between is a simple comparison of the three operand.

Comment: it works only unique record but when I entered duplicate records, it gives an error 

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

The `BETWEEN` operator is pulling all of the results from 'Kaushambi' and 'Maholi', alphabetically based on the column `placeName`. I believe you're thinking that your table is static, and you're expecting it to retrieve results based on the order that they appear on your screen in the initial query. That is incorrect.

Table rows are stored as an unordered set of data, and rows are returned in the order the optimizer finds them, unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause.

You can retrieve rows by `placeName`, but if that's the only column you're considering, the order will be alphabetical.

Try `BETWEEN 'Bareilly' AND 'Hapur'`, for example, to see the top half (again, alphabetically) of your result set, even though sorting by ID there are no rows between them.